# How do I reshape a 2d array into a 3d array for a neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I had a dataset where I apply `train_test_split`. Shape of X:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1945, 10000)
(487, 10000)
```

As X is numpy array, it needed to convert into image (3D), so that Neural Network would be applied at later. So, I applied:

```
X_train_3d = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],100,100).astype('float32')    # X_train.shape[1] = 10000 ; 
                                                                            # where 10000 = 100*100;
X_test_3d = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],100,100).astype('float32')

print(X_train_3d.shape)
print(X_test_3d.shape)
```

So, I got my expected result:

```
(1945, 100, 100)
(487, 100, 100)
```

And I built Neural Network like this way:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100, 100)),  # width, height of image 100,100
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(39)  # total number of target = 39
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_3d, y_train, epochs=10)
```

Now, I am working with a dataset and trying to apply a similar logic. After splitting:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1945, 1800)
(487, 1800)
```

Now, I don't understand how to define reshape like:

```
X_train_3d = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],?,?).astype('float32')
```

As square root of 1800 is not integer. How to convert it into 3d, so that I will be able to build Neural Network like previous.

Comment: why not go for something like `X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 30, 60).astype('float32')`? It doesn't have to be a square.

Comment: Actaully, I am very new in this context. That's why, I thought it should be a square. With those values, should I run this like this then: `keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(30, 60)),` ?

Comment: i think there's something fundamentally wrong here. if it's 3D data, why isn't it already in 3D format? how is the data entered? there are questions you need to answer before your problem can be solved. and why are you reshaping it to a square just to flatten it again? this makes zero sense. what is your reason for wanting 3D arrays?

Comment: well, my dataset (excel file) is either pixel value of images (0-255) or ROS values (0-1) of the images. And it's (X_train, X_test) 2D obviously. I wanted to build Neural Network so that I wanted to converted that into 3D. Sorry, I am new. That's why, I could not use proper terms.

Comment: and they are different sizes, and you don't know the size and/or if they are square? reshaping them to a square will just yield random pixels

Comment: Well, the original images are in square format (100 * 100). But, I am not working with those images. For some learning process, I am working with multiple csv/exel files generated from those images. There are multiple generate files because some are containing original pixel value, some are ROS values, augmented etc. As you can see, at my first example, I was able to keep it in square format `(1945, 10000)` which is the original dimension of the images too `10000 = 100 * 100`. But, I don't understand what to do with my X_train & X_test of second dataset (shape is `(1945, 1800)`
`(487, 1800)`)

Comment: Without reshaping, If I run `model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)`, I got: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1945, 1800)`

Comment: I don't think it would be right for anyone to give an answer right now. Unless you find the solution for your data, reshaping the arrays will essentially be random pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make this run is without a CNN. Then, you just don't have to reshape. Speculative reshaping would just yield random pixels.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

X = np.random.randint(0, 256, (1945, 1800)) # fake data
y = np.random.randint(0, 38, 1945)

model = Sequential([
            Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(1800,)),
            Dense(39)])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
              from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

Ideally, you would fix your data and then you could run a CNN, which is the best model for this. A CNN maintains 2D relationships between pixels so it would be fantastic, but there is no relationship between your pixels if you don't know the correct shape.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. And I don't want to run CNN for this dataset becasue of the shape. I will run CNN for my first dataset (first example) as there is correct shape. But, for my second dataset (second example), I just wanted to run  a basic NN. But, without correct shape, I didn't understand how to build the basic NN.

Comment: Okay I understand. I was confused because you posted an error message with a convolutional layer earlier. I thought you wanted to fit a CNN

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to clearify everything. Like I said before, I am new at ml, so that I might be failed to use proper terms/explaination sometimes. Thanks for your help.